# Почему при создании нового события возникает ошибка?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Дорабатываю чужую программу :( На главной форме создаю текстбокс, хочу сделать поиск - фильтровать датагрид, при вводе в текстбокс номера договора. Назначаю текстбоксу событие TextCahged (пробовал KeyDown, KeyPress) и при запуске вылезает ошибка.[image] Если убрать событие - запускается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что после изменения не собирается дебаг вариант программы. Я бы посоветовал провести переборку или почистить выходные файлы в папках bin и obj чтобы студия их пересобрала при компиляции.

Comment: Делал ребилд, восстанавливал проект из бэкапа... не помогает...

Comment: Проблема решилась отключением антивируса (avast! что-то он последние пару недель очень уж агрессивный...)

Comment: Советую Вам в настройках антивируса указать visaul studio как исключение для проверки, а то он каждый раз при сборке делает проверку.

Comment: Только не Visual Studio, а каталог, где лежат проекты же!